# Survey of market making strategies and research

Tags: high-frequency, market-making

I am undergoing a focused study of market making theory. So far, I've encountered the following papers:

- [Market Making and Mean Reversion](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~mkearns/papers/marketmaking.pdf)
- [Adapting to a Market Shock: Optimal Sequential
  Market-Making](http://machinelearning.wustl.edu/mlpapers/paper_files/NIPS2008_0272.pdf)
- [Rational Market Making with Probabilistic Knowledge](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~sandholm/ratoinalMarketMakingWProbabilisticKnowledge.aamas12.pdf)
- [Market Maker Inventories and Stock Prices](http://www.seasholes.com/files/Paper_Hendershott_Seasholes_2007_AER_P_P.pdf)
- [High Frequency Trading and The New-Market Makers](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1722924)
- [High-frequency trading in a limit order book](http://www.finance-concepts.com/images/fc/HighFrequencyTrading.pdf)
- [Dealing with the Inventory Risk. A solution to the market making problem](http://arxiv.org/abs/1105.3115)

What important papers on market making am I missing?

[To constrain the field a little, I'm interested in market making highly liquid equities where the market maker operates at latencies no larger than the competition.]